# How to setup hook_install to have a geometry field on a POSTGIS database?

Tags: 7, installation

From a module, I would like to create a table containing a POSTGIS geometry field.
I guess I need to use hook_install but can't find any definition of a geometry field anywhere. How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work (don't have a postgis install handy to test), but try

```
$schema['table'] = array(
  'fields' => array(
    'some_geom_field' => array(
      'pgsql_type' => 'geom',
      ...
    ),
  ),
);
```

If that doesn't do it I think you're out of luck using `hook_schema()`, you'll probably need to execute a custom SQL script instead.